# Partial gin index does not work with WHERE

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE m2m_entries_n_elements(
  entry_id UUID
  element_id UUID
  value JSONB
)
```

Value is jsonb object in following format: `{<type>: <value>}`

And I want to create GIN index only for `number` values:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_element_value_number
ON m2m_entries_n_elements
USING GIN (element_id, CAST(value ->> 'number' AS INT))
WHERE value ? 'number';
```

But when I use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` I see that index does not work:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM m2m_entries_n_elements WHERE CAST(value ->> 'number' AS INT) = 2;

Seq Scan on m2m_entries_n_elements  (cost=0.00..349.02 rows=50 width=89) (actual time=0.013..2.087 rows=1663 loops=1)
Filter: (((value ->> 'number'::text))::integer = 2)
Rows Removed by Filter: 8338
Planning Time: 0.042 ms
Execution Time: 2.150 ms
```

But if I remove `WHERE value ? 'number'` from creating the index, it starts working:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on m2m_entries_n_elements  (cost=6.39..70.29 rows=50 width=89) (actual time=0.284..0.819 rows=1663 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (((value ->> 'number'::text))::integer = 2)
  Heap Blocks: exact=149
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_elements  (cost=0.00..6.38 rows=50 width=0) (actual time=0.257..0.258 rows=1663 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (((value ->> 'number'::text))::integer = 2)
Planning Time: 0.207 ms
Execution Time: 0.922 ms
```

Comment: In order for the partial index to be used, you need to have the same WHERE clause as the index. And if you don't use `element_id` then the `cast(...)`  expression should be the first expression in the index. But I fail to see why you would need a GIN index for this. A plain btree index seems more appropriate.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks. It works with `AND value ? 'number'`. I know that I need use `element_id` first in `where` but to my surprise the index works without it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have a general theorem prover.  Maybe you intuit that `value ->> 'number'` being defined implies that `value ? 'number'` is true, but PostgreSQL doesn't know that.  You would need to explicitly include the `?` condition in your query to get use of the index.

But PostgreSQL is smart enough to know that `CAST(value ->> 'number' AS INT) = 2` does imply that the LHS can't be null, so if you create the partial index `WHERE value ->> 'number' IS NOT NULL` then it will get used with no change to your query.